# Fragments ViewPager as Play Store App?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I required to develop an App which will look similar to Android Play Store Application or else like [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eurosport&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5ldXJvc3BvcnQiXQ..). I Read many tutorials and find almost every tutorial with similar examples as [this one](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/).

I have started with my App and done with Sample ViewPager with Fragments containing all Static data shown in the above example. Now I want to fetch the WS data as Playstore app or above given Example app. I have done a sample but it will store the Fragment Data of 1,2 fragments only and when I go for 3rd fragment, it loses the 1st fragment and loses 2nd fragment when go to 4th fragment.

How to achieve the above architecture and get it done.

**UPDATED:**

I am using FragmentPagerAdapter for which, in which it is saving only two or three fragments data.

Comment: Try with `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev I already used 'FragmentPagerAdapter'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)`

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

The default limit is 1. It is also the minimum limit (needed for the sliding animation).

Comment: If I set as 2, then it will retain the 2 number of pages. but I require that no page has to be recreated.

Comment: If you have 3 fragments, you can set the limit as 2. That way all 3 of your fragments will be retained.

Comment: I have 7 Fragments to do so as PlayStore App if I set offscreenpagelimit for 3 or 4 will it do? doesn't it create any Memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

You should fetch data from some kind of source **inside** fragment itself. So, when it become visible (i.e. when `onCreateView` is called) fragment should fill itself with some data.

If you are working with network, then you should:

1. Fetch data from your `ContentProvider` (or SQLite database directly, but for below explanation only `ContentProvider` is suitable) that were cached from previous network request.
2. Start your own `Service` to perform upload from server.
3. As soon as data will be loaded, save it into your `ContentProvider` (only `ContentProvider` is suitable here, because we are working across process boundaries. However, `ContentProvider` itself can be based (and usually it is) on SQLit` database).
4. Notify your fragment (usually by binding to `Service`, and listening it's state) that data is loaded and ready to be fetched.
5. Fetch data from `ContentProvider` (same as 1)

Of course, this is not the only way (but I prefer that one). [See video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE&list=WL13A4DA03A80DA509) from Google I\O (that I've just shortly explained).